# How to let the parameters of the functions in andorid studio stay in Single line on code formatting?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

On pressing ctrl+alt+L android studio formats the code but it also places all of the function parameters on different lines, how can I stop this from happening. This function below

```
private fun paintWithColor(list: MutableList<Button>, colorID: Int, index: Int) {
    list[index].setBackgroundColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            this,
            colorID
        )
    )
}
```

becomes this

```
private fun paintWithColor(
    list: MutableList<Button>,
    colorID: Int,
    index: Int
) {
    list[index].setBackgroundColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            this,
            colorID
        )
    )
}
```

How can I stop this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the wrapping options at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Kotlin | Wrapping and Braces | Method declaration parameters. Set to **Do not wrap**.